# Using jQuery to show/hide <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code that's below. Each of the div tags is set by the CSS to `display: none;` , nothing else. I want the select box to show only the selected div and its contents, but hide the rest of them. I feel like I'm just missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. I'm using jQuery 1.8.1. Thanks in advance!

*As a note, I edited [this link's](http://anthonygthomas.com/2010/03/14/display-form-fields-based-on-selection-using-jquery/) code for my purposes. I'm not phenomenal with javascript, which is why this is likely terrible.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#choices").change(function(){

if ($(this).val() == "option1" ) {

    $("#option1").slideDown("fast");
    $("#option2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option3").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option4").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option5").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option6").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option7").slideUp("fast");

} 

if ($(this).val() == "option2" ) {

    $("#option1").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option2").slideDown("fast");
    $("#option3").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option4").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option5").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option6").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option7").slideUp("fast");

} 

if ($(this).val() == "option3" ) {

    $("#option1").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option3").slideDown("fast");
    $("#option4").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option5").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option6").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option7").slideUp("fast");

} 

if ($(this).val() == "option4" ) {

    $("#option1").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option3").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option4").slideDown("fast");
    $("#option5").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option6").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option7").slideUp("fast");

} 

if ($(this).val() == "option5" ) {

    $("#option1").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option3").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option4").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option5").slideDown("fast");
    $("#option6").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option7").slideUp("fast");

} 

if ($(this).val() == "option6" ) {

    $("#option1").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option3").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option4").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option5").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option6").slideDown("fast");
    $("#option7").slideUp("fast");

} 

if ($(this).val() == "option7" ) {

    $("#option1").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option3").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option4").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option5").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option6").slideUp("fast");
    $("#option7").slideDown("fast");

} 

});
</script>
random body text
<form>
<select id="choices">
    <option value="none">Select one...</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
</select>
</form>
    <div id="option1" class="hide">Opt 1 Text</div>
    <div id="option2" class="hide">Opt 2 Text</div>
    <div id="option3" class="hide">Opt 3 Text</div>
    <div id="option4" class="hide">Opt 4 Text</div>
    <div id="option5" class="hide">Opt 5 Text</div>
    <div id="option6" class="hide">Opt 6 Text</div>
    <div id="option7" class="hide">Opt 7 Text</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using class selector for selecting element by ID, you should use `#` instead of `.`, jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors. You can also minify your code.

```
$("#choices").change(function(){ 
   $('.hide').slideUp();
   $('#'+this.value).slideDown()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X7AbR/

Comment: I just updated my code, both here and on my actual form, but it still isn't working.

Comment: I guess it's from the fact that I'm running it on WordPress then; I'll need to play with the WP side of things. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

your selector is using:

```
$('.optionX')
```

when it should be:

```
$('#optionX')
```

this is because 'optionX' is an ID and not a class. if it were a class, '.optionX' would work.

Comment: I just realized this and I updated the code appropriately. It doesn't work, unfortunately. I think it's because I'm on WordPress. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

wow... Someone hasn't heard of DRY ("Don't Repeat Yourself"). One simple loop will kill all of that code:

```
$("#choices").change(function() {
  for( var i=1; i<=7; i++) {
      $("#option"+i)["slide"+($(this).val() == "option"+i ? "Down" : "Up")]("fast");
  }
});
```

Also note I fixed your problem: `.choices` refers to any element with `choices` in the Class Name. `#choices` refers to the element with the ID `choices`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with loops in javascript; I only know the bare minimum. I'll try this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong css selectors to get the elements.

`$(".choices").change(function(){`

The `.` selector selects elements by classname, and you have no elements with the class "choices", what you want here is `$("#choices")` which selects by id.

The same applies to your option selections, where you select by class with `.` while you have elements with the ids that should be selected with `#`

Resources:

[jQuery id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

[jQuery class-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

[jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I just realized this myself, and I updated it. It still doesn't work, unfortunately. I think it's because I'm on WordPress. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are wrong.  You are using ids in your html, but classes in your jquery.  To fix it change

`$(".choices")` to `$("#choices")`

`$(".optionX")` to `$("#optionX")`

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/UDKrA/10/

Comment: I just realized this, and I updated it. It still doesn't work, unfortunately. I think it's because I'm on WordPress. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Build your selector dynamically and employ the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
$("#choices").change(function(){ // that's an ID, not a class
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#'+val).slideDown('fast').siblings('.hide').slideUp('fast');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/QkNX4/